# Magento 2 Guest Checkout is disable but still getting spammed with failed transactions checkout via guest

Tags: magento2

I am having hardtime with a Magento 2 at my work where occasionally  got spammed with hundred of failed transactions in a short amount of time checkout with a 3rd party payment gateway.

Guest Checkout Feature is already disabled but somehow the log shows that the failed transactions were checkout as guest.

Does anyone know if there is any method the hackers use to spam orders on Magento 2?

Magento Version: 2.4.3-p1

Default Luma Theme

Thanks

Comment: We're also having this issue and I can't track down why/how it's happening. No orders are successfully going through but it's still annoying to purge guest Customers that should have never been able to be created.